# Filter Excel data based on non-standardised date data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel XLSX document that contains a simple list of records, with each record having an associated start and end date column.  For reasons out of my control, the start/end dates can contain multiple dates in a single cell, and with one part of the cell value being struck off using strikethrough formatting.  Please see examples of the primary records in the following screenshot:

[image]

I have no control over this and cannot change it (I tried, but customer says no).

Now, I am trying to build another worksheet in this document that will filter the primary data based on some criteria.  The first criteria I'm trying to filter by is to only show records which have a start date greater than `TODAY()`.

I started by checking if I could get the right dates, first and foremost.  The following formula was tested against D19, and returns the correct date from the cell:

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A19,SEARCH(":",A19,1)-13,10))
```

> ***Result equals "27/10/2023", which is correct.***

Now I am trying to combine this with the FILTER formula on the start date column, with some string manipulation to manage the odd date format, but not having so much luck.  My current formula is as follows (where 'Primary' is the named range where main data is stored, and Primary!A:A is the start date column in this range):

```
=FILTER(Primary,DATEVALUE(MID(Primary!A:A,SEARCH(":",Primary!A:A,1)-13,10))>=TODAY(),"No Results")
```

This gives me `#VALUE!` error.

Is this possible to solve using the FILTER formula, or am I going to need to try something else?  The one rule is that I can't touch/change anything on the Primary worksheet at all.

Comment: Firstly, if you think your formula is going to do the trick, but you're getting #VALUE, you really need to break the formula down into its component parts an interrogate the values that each level of the formula will be returning, so that you can work out where the error is occurring

Comment: This can be fixed can you post a sample data using **[Markdown_Table_Generator](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/)**, also confirm whether you are using `MS365` in current channel, if yes, you can parse those unwanted dates using `TEXTAFTER()` function.

Comment: Is there actually consistency in how the values in the field end up?  Is it always the end of the strings that contains the "valid" date and time?

Comment: @Craig, yes the last date is the correct valid date/time.  The date format can only be either like "Sunday 22/10/2023 Saturday 21/10/2023 23:00" (with the first date being struck out) or "Saturday 21/10/2023 23:00".

Comment: You could try a formula like this, it will work and it can be improvised if you post some sample data so we can reproduce the solution more accurately `=LET(x,FILTER(Primary,Primary!D:D<>""),y,DROP(x,,1),FILTER(x,TEXTAFTER(y," ",-3,,,y)/1>=TODAY(),"No Results")))`

Comment: @DRVR two lines of data is not considered or good for sampling or testing, you should post at least 8/10 lines of data including the other columns, your sample data need not to be the original one you have but at least it resembles with the actual. The reason I ask, so we can help you out with a proper solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have commented above that it can be solved using <kbd>TEXTAFTER( )</kbd>, so here is the solution, also if you are referring the whole columns, then use the second approach, or it would be better to convert the original range of data into a `Structured References` aka Tables.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _Primary, A2:C16,
     _startDate, TAKE(_Primary,,1),
     FILTER(_Primary,INT(TEXTAFTER(_startDate," ",-2,,,_startDate)/1)>=TODAY()))
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _lastRow, MATCH(2,1/(A:A<>"")),
     _Primary, A2:INDEX(A:C,_lastRow,),
     _startDate, TAKE(_Primary,,1),
     FILTER(_Primary, INT(TEXTAFTER(_startDate," ",-2,,,_startDate)/1)>=TODAY(),"No-Results"))
```

---

**Notes:** the sample data may vary with the OP as i was not able to convert the whole data from screenshot to excel.

---

I am adding another step to the above solutions, to ensure that the dates which compared to <kbd>TODAY()</kbd> are actual dates which Excel understands.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _Primary, A2:C20,
     _startDate, TAKE(_Primary,,1),
     _datesAsText, MID(TEXTAFTER(_startDate," ",-2,,,_startDate),{4,1,7},{2,2,4}),
     _dateConversion, BYROW(_datesAsText,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN("/",,x)/1)),
     FILTER(_Primary,_dateConversion>=TODAY()))
```

---

Comment: I just noticed the strikethrough formatting wasn't carried accross; do you know if this is possible to achieve easilly?

Comment: @DRVR no formatting carries forward using formula unfortunately! For that you need VBA for the whole process!

Comment: Argh, I was hoping to avoid a macro/VBA solution, but it looks like I won't have a choice.  Thanks again anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

### Filter By Date Being Part of a String

- This will replace the 'odd' dates with actual dates. If you don't want that, replace `HSTACK(dates,DROP(data,,1))` with `data`.

```
=LET(data,Primary,
    dates,IFERROR(DATEVALUE(TRIM(TEXTAFTER(INDEX(data,,1)," ",-2))),),
FILTER(HSTACK(dates,DROP(data,,1)),dates>=TODAY(),"No Results"))
```